# Text only getting correct UNICODE if i echo an arabic text before CURL

Tags: php, curl, unicode

I have a php code that is supposed to curl a json file that contains arabic text and show it.

the code wont show the arabic text with the right unicode unless i echo an arabic text ( even if a single letter ) before the curl statement

**The Working Code**

```
@header('charset=utf-8'); 
$echo= "العربية";
$url="http://cinema.sabriapps.com/json.php"; 

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER,array ("Content-Type: text/xml; charset=UTF|-8",));
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,$url);
$result=curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);

var_dump($result);
```

**The Broken Code :(**

```
@header('charset=utf-8'); 
// NO ECHO
$url="http://cinema.sabriapps.com/json.php"; 

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER,array ("Content-Type: text/xml; charset=UTF|-8",));
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,$url);
$result=curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);

var_dump($result);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
header('Content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8');
```

instead of

```
@header('charset=utf-8');
```

`charset=utf-8` is not a valid HTTP response header so it is not having any effect on the encoding of the page.